# How do I require HTTPS for my Swagger document and swagger UI using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

How can I disable the HTTP endpoints for my Swagger document and Swagger UI using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v4.0.1?

We require HTTPS for all services and want to do that for documentation as well.

I've looked for documentation on this but I haven't found any for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. I've seen some [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625000/how-do-i-get-swagger-ui-to-use-port-443-with-swashbuckle) for the non-Core version but the referenced properties/methods are not available on Core.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up automatic redirection to HTTPS in Startup.cs is how I ended up solving this issue:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```