# Swagger UI always returning error code

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

I am integrating swagger API with spring mvc REST. When I am trying to load the json data in swagger UI i am always getting error code when i see my method. It should return a valid output with the types to change.

I cannot figure out whats going on here, did I miss something in my configuration ?
I am using mangofactory

Comment: please share the configurations you are using.

Comment: <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: one more thing that i have noticed my request url is always null when i hit try it now button of swagger API

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36542927/5934435